# Deployment server changing to a new server with different IP address

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have Server1 (Publishing server which has source code), Server 2 (Deployment server) and Clients machine which already has applications used and pointing to Server2. Would like to move this server 2 to new server and remove the server2. I do not want to change it manually in the client's systems. And this server 2 and new server are going to hold different IP addresses. How can i change the server 2 to new server. Please some one suggest me a solution ASAP.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using click-once deployment, you can change the DNS of the domain to point to the second server, and put the files in the same virtual path, There should be no problems.

Comment: Thank you. We are using click-once deployment. But i would like to remove the current deployment server completely and replace with a new server. How i can do that?

Comment: Keep it for a small time for backup issues, and when you find that there are no problems, you can remove the first server, or use it for other issues.

Comment: Alright !! So, i need to change the DNS in the current deployment server to point to the new deployment server. Right? And at the point, i want to remove the old server and keep the new server, how can i do that.

Comment: You should publish the files to the second server before changing the DNS, After the DNS propagated to all customers, (give this 24 hours maximum), you can do whatever you do on the first server, you can turn it off or disconnect it :).

Comment: Hmm.... Finally, here is my understanding. Correct me if i am wrong.       1. I will copy all the files to the new server and publish them.                        2. I will change the DNS in the current server to point to the new server.                                                                   I will keep the current server for some time and i am not touching the clients system but it is working. At the time i want to remove the old server and keep the new server, and i do not want to touch the client's system, how DNS propagates to all customers if there is no old server.

Comment: And put them on the same virtual-path

Comment: Hmm.... Finally, here is my understanding. Correct me if i am wrong. 1. I will copy all the files to the new server and publish them. 2. I will change the DNS in the current server to point to the new server. I will keep the current server for some time and i am not touching the clients system but it is working. At the time i want to remove the old server and keep the new server, and i do not want to touch the client's system, how DNS propagates to all customers if there is no old server.

Comment: You are right, the propagation will not take more than 24 hours.

Comment: But how the clients machine knows about this new server if there is no   current server. Client's machine is pointing to the current server and  here, we are changing the DNS to new server. But if we remove the current server, client machine still points to the current one??? How the propagation will be done.

Comment: When you are changing the DNS, clients will getting the correct IP from the cache of internet providers, this cache will be invalidated for all internet providers in less than 24 hours, when the cash invalidates, the clients will get the new IP. I am not a network specialist :) I have a general information about this, you can read more here: http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/?id=797 or else ware.

Comment: But I am planning to such scenario at the moment for my server :)

Comment: This information helps a lot. And also the link is very useful. Thank you very much :) Also, do let me know once you try this scenario with your server :)

Comment: can u pls check  my question here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195754/how-to-import-csv-file-in-to-access-db-using-c-sharp